# Alternative package servers for Ubuntu Server 23.04 Lunar Lobster

Tags: apt

I'm currently getting 300KB/sec from the Ubuntu archive servers, and it's blocking me from getting work done efficiently. Are there any alternative package servers, ideally that support HTTPS, that I can use to grab Lunar Lobster packages for my Ubuntu Server minimal install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the known, registered Ubuntu mirrors are listed at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Simply edit your apt sources to one you prefer.